# Credentials in the realms export data of keyCloak

Tags: security, keycloak, jdbcrealm, idp

As per my understanding  , we can do import or export realms data of keycloak by specifying some java opts on keycloak startup.

Regarding data export , the exported realms json data will also the have the credentials? If yes , then it won't cause security issues as anyone can check the credentials by opening the exported json file.

Answer (score 1):

> Regarding data export , the exported realms json data will also the
> have the credentials?

Yes, if you use the option `-Dkeycloak.migration.action=export` during the keycloak started up. However, from the [Keycloak Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/):

> **Keycloak collects user credentials, such as password, OTP codes, and
> WebAuthn public keys. This information is encrypted and saved in a
> database, so it is not visible to Keycloak administrators.** However,
> each type of credential can include non-confidential metadata that is
> visible to administrators such as the algorithm that is used to hash
> the password and the number of hash iterations used to hash the
> password.

The same applies to the Json File as long as the passwords are encrypted it *is fine*.